# how to pass provider classname as an argument?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I want to pass  provider classname as an argument but it keeps giving me error The name 'providerClassName' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.

I am trying this

```
  Widget buildText<T>({@required T providerClassName}) {
    return Text(
        Provider.of<providerClassName>(context, listen: false).username);
  }
```

and i am calling function like this

```
 buildText(providerClassName: HomeScreenProvider);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it correct.
You have the generic  type `T` of the method

```dart
buildText<T extends HomeScreenProvider>
```

so you can use it like `Provider.of<T>(context, listen: false).username` and call it
`buildText<HomeScreenProvider>();`

Comment: it worked thanks man. but i cannot access username it is giving me error The getter 'username' isn't defined for the type 'T'.
Try importing the library that defines 'username', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'username'.

Comment: Do you have different providers (like HomeScreenProvider, etc ) that extend a single parent Provider which has a member variable `username` ?

Comment: my HomeScreenProvider looks like this  HomeScreenProvider extends ChangeNotifier { String username = "soumya"; }

Comment: I edited the answer. You will need to change the definition to `buildText<T extends HomeScreenProvider>`